# Entity Framework Core: Include on TPH

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

We have the following model in EFCore set up using Table Per Hierarchy (simplified for clarity):

```
public class User {
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class Student : User {
  public Company Company { get; set; }
}
public class Teacher : User {
  public Company School { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get all users (both Students and Teachers) with all references included. Basically I want to do the following in one query:

```
_context.Users.OfType<Teacher>().Include(x => x.School);
_context.Users.OfType<Student>().Include(x => x.Company);
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: In reality the query involves pagination (I want to display first 10 users sorted by Id, regardless whether they are teachers or students)

Comment: You need to wait for [EF Core 2.1](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/Roadmap#features-we-have-committed-to-complete) - [Include for derived types](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/3910) item

Comment: thanks, that actually answers my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Ivan's comment, current (pre EFCore 2.1) solution is:

```
var users = _context.Users.Where(_filter_conditions_here).Skip().Take(_if_you_like_);
var userIds = users.Select(x => x.Id).ToList()
_context.Users.OfType<Teacher>().Where(x => userIds.Contain(x.Id)).Include(x => x.School).ToList();
_context.Users.OfType<Student>().Where(x => userIds.Contain(x.Id)).Include(x => x.Company).ToList();
```